# Analytic image using 2-D Hilbert transform

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing

I am working on a problem of phase (/phase derivative) retrieval from **closed fringe patterns**. The paper https://opg.optica.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-58-16-4420&id=413113 which uses a pseudo-Wigner Ville distribution (PSWVD) to directly estimate the unwrapped phase derivative is what I want to implement. 
The PSWVD method requires a complex signal (here, complex/analytic image). The authors have applied the method to holographic interferometry where one gets the complex signal by default. But I am interested in applying the method to photoelastic fringe patterns(another interferometric technique) where one gets only closed fringe patterns (i.e., real part of the complex signal). So, I need to perform real to analytic image conversion before implementing PSWVD.

For experimentation, a Gaussian phase is simulated (as shown below)

[image]

The real part of the signal exp(i*phi*) based on the simulated phase will be cos(*phi*). This is the closed fringe pattern, which is given below:

[image]

The aim is to obtain an analytic image, i.e, get the sin(*phi*) image from cos(*phi*) image using Hilbert transform to define the analytic image of the form exp(i*phi*).

After applying the 2-D Hilbert transform (available in the scipy module) on the cos(*phi*) image, the result obtained is:

[image]

This is clearly not the sin(*phi*) image. The true sin(*phi*) image is given below:
[image]

Later, I found that this is reported in literature as half plane Hilbert complex image and this real to analytic image conversion is quite involved than a simple function call.

I found that introducing spatial carrier to the real fringe pattern and then applying Hilbert transform is a possible way out. But I am not quite sure how this works as I am not from a signal processing background. I would highly appreciate it if someone can point me to the right resources concerning this (mainly on spatial carriers or single image real to analytic coversion)?

**PS:**

  ->  I have been told that phase shifting method can also be used for constructing the analytic image, but this requires multiple images to be captured experimentally. I am interested in single image real to analytic conversion for which spatial carrier fringe method was recommended.
  ->  I am aware of the closed fringe techniques that are based on iterative optimization, but since experimentally I can easily introduce a spatial carrier, I preferred this method over the others.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks for the reply. I am using the hilbert transform method available in the scipy module (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) . Here, changing the axis is found to have no effect on the result.

I didn't quite get what you meant by other estimates of gradient, do you mean phase gradient? It would be helpful if you can elaborate a bit on this. 
Thanks for the suggestion, I will try the DSP stack exchange.

Comment: nevermind. I clearly don't have the domain knowledge to infer what you really need. the pictures in your question look too simple to be the whole truth. -- this looks relevant? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0143816619301216

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, the aim is phase derivative retrieval (as implemented in the paper cited in the question) from closed fringe patterns (obtained from the experimental technique that I use called photoelasticity). Since the original work used open fringe patterns (complex image) and I have access to only closed fringe pattern from my experimental technique, a real to analytic image conversion was necessary. I have put simple images to easily communicate the point that the default Hilbert transform was not working for this case. I will look into the paper you have shared. Thanks for your time